# Unity not scrolling when mouse not over object

Tags: unity, ui-design, scrolling

In Unity I am using a scroll view. It works semi-perfectly (had a lot of problems with it, don't like how the UI system works).

The content for my scroll view is a bunch of buttons aligned vertically with some spacing between them. The problem is that the scroll rect will only scroll if I'm hovering over one of the buttons. If the mouse is between two buttons, it won't scroll.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Hirearchy]

[image: Scroll rect]

[image: Scroll bar]

Also, you may see that I'm not using the standard Scroll Rect, mine is nothing special, just disabled the dragging that is stupid to be used on non-touch devices.

Comment: Add `Image` component to your `ScrollView` so it looks like a background and tick `RaycastTarget`. Set it's color opacity to 0f and tell me if that works.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! If you want you can reply with an actual answer and mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ScrollView` by default has an `Image` component with a `RaycastTarget` enabled like on the image below.

[image]

In order to detect touch and clicks, `UI` elements need to have at least one component with `RaycastTarget` enabled.

Your `ScrollView` doesn't have the default Image background so it doesn't respond to clicks. Add `Image` component to your `ScrollView` so it looks like a background and tick `RaycastTarget`. Set it's color opacity to `0f` and voilà :)